# How to show star rating on ckan for datasets

Tags: python, ckan

I have used ckanext-qa but its seems its not as per my requirement I am looking for extension by which Logged in user can be able to rate form 1 to 5 for each dataset over ckan.

Anybody have an idea how to do like that

Comment: To avoid confusion with the well-known '5 stars of openness' provided by QA, I suggest you change the title to "How to allow users to rate datasets in CKAN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any extensions that do this.

You could write one to add this info in a dataset extra field. You may wish to store it as JSON and record the ratings given by each user.

Alternatively you could try the `rating_create` API function - this is old functionality which has no UI, but it may just do what you want.

Comment: i understand but i cannot render 5 star rating on UI like additional_info.html  jquery is not working to put user rating through jinja UI. and when i tried to call api seems its not working